# Corrupt InnoDB tables after every mysql restart. What's wrong?

Tags: mysql, innodb

Recently I changed a few settings in my mysql configuration. I did the following:
- stop mysql
- save the changed settings
- delete all ibdata and ib_logfiles
- start mysql

Normally this works fine but recently, everytime I do it, all my InnoDB tables get currupted. What am I doing wrong?

My settings:

```
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
key_buffer = 16K
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_cache = 4
thread_cache = 16
sort_buffer_size = 64K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 256K
net_buffer_length = 2K
thread_stack = 64K

#skip-networking
server-id   = 1

# Uncomment the following if you want to log updates
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# Uncomment the following if you are NOT using BDB tables
skip-bdb

# Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
innodb_data_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql/
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql/
innodb_log_arch_dir = /var/lib/mysql/
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 400M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 30M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 400M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 8M
sort_buffer_size = 8M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 8M
sort_buffer_size = 8M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

Comment: Why are you deleting the ibdata file? This is probably the source of your corrupted tables. Can you post error logs info from mysql startup?

Comment: When I change the innodb_log_file_size, I have to remove the file. The same thing happens when I do NOT delete this file.

Comment: I'll post the error logs after checking a few more things.

Comment: @marcus to change the innodb_log_file_size all you should have to do is delete the log files (not ibdata). See http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/how-to-safely-change-mysql-innodb-variable-innodb-log-file-size

Comment: @DTest, yes you're absolutely right. I don't know where I had it from that the ibdata files had to be deleted as well...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

markus you want to read the very last paragraph on mysql.com docs for resizing log file http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-data-log-reconfiguration.html - you only need to remove the ib_ log files and not the ibdata1 file

> Stop the MySQL server and make sure that it shuts down without errors
>   (to ensure that there is no information for outstanding transactions
>   in the log). Copy the old log files into a safe place in case
>   something went wrong during the shutdown and you need them to recover
>   the tablespace. Delete the old log files from the log file directory,
>   edit my.cnf to change the log file configuration, and start the MySQL
>   server again. mysqld sees that no InnoDB log files exist at startup
>   and creates new ones.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish by resizing and deleting log files, but I'll take it at face value that it's a required workflow.

If you wish to delete your ibdata and ib_logfiles, I recommend setting up your config file include [multiple tablespaces](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html):

```
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table
```

Then import/create your schemas.

This will separate out the table data and structure from the default location, thus making it less confusing for you for your re-size and delete required work flow.