# Is this Dedicated Server good enough to Run MySQL on Linux Ubuntu?

Tags: mysql, innodb, hardware

I have a web application that runs simple logic. Most of the SQL procedures that I have
only do simple selects, some simple join table and some simple inserts. I want to get
a dedicated server for My Database, I found one but I didn't get it yet. I want to get
some of your opinion on this machine before paying for it. I know I can benchmark it
but only after I own it. So any idea if this one is enough for 5000 users per day doing
simple reads and simple insertion into MySQL with InnoDB Engine ?

- Core i5 Quad Core i5-2400 3.10 GHz
- 16 GB DDR3-1333 UDIMM
- 250 GB SATA HDD (7200 RPM)
- 100 Mbps Uplink Port Speed
- Ubuntu 10.04 - 64 Bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to know / to figure out:

Even some simple reads, could be IO hungry.
And the amount of users doesn't tell us how many request ( read / write).

Without more data, it hard to tell, but that seem to be a good server. I believe that it'll be good enough, but that's just a opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Two things catch my attention

- MEMORY
- CPU

I have addressed these issue in past posts

- [Is the CPU performance relevant for a database server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17092/is-the-cpu-performance-relevant-for-a-database-server/17098#17098)
- [Insert-heavy InnoDB table won't use all my CPU](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10899/insert-heavy-innodb-table-wont-use-all-my-cpu/10900#10900)

Please follow suggestions centered around InnoDB as multiple core engagement is only available in MySQL 5.5's native InnoDB as well Percona's XtraDB.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I really appreciate your opinion. It meant a lot to me :)