# How to update mysql my.cnf without getting error?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5, my.cnf

I updated the MySQL `my.conf` file and and restarted my server without a problem.

As soon as I tried to access a table I received the error

```
mysql #1033 - Incorrect information in file:
```

I reverted the `my.cnf` file back to the original and the server is working properly.

I am looking to update some of the innodb settings:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size
innodb_log_file_size
innodb_log_buffer_size
```

I think I am seeing that I have to update the `my.cnf` file before creating any databases on the server, but that doesn't seem right.

Is there a way to update the `my.cnf` file after a database has been created on the server?

CentOS 5.6

MySQL 5.0.77

Original:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Default to using old password format for compatibility with mysql 3.x
# clients (those using the mysqlclient10 compatibility package).
old_passwords=1

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks;
# to do so, uncomment this line:
# symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

New:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Default to using old password format for compatibility with mysql 3.x
# clients (those using the mysqlclient10 compatibility package).
old_passwords=1

# This is my configuration!
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=20M

innodb_log_file_size=1G
innodb_log_buffer_size=8M

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks;
# to do so, uncomment this line:
# symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned these four options

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size
innodb_log_file_size
innodb_log_buffer_size
```

The one that worries me is `innodb_log_file_size`

Upon initial startup, [**innodb_log_file_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size) is 5MB. You need to make new InnoDB log files. There are two InnoDB log files that got created 5MB each:

- `/var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0`
- `/var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1`

All you have to do is the following:

```
service mysql stop
rm -f ib_logfile*
service mysql start
```

The two log files will be regenerated as 1GB files. [I wrote about this last year](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/1265/877).

Give it a Try !!!

BTW DO NOT TOUCH /var/lib/mysql/ibata1 !!!