# How can I tune MySQL to behave better under load

Tags: mysql, performance

We have a typical master-slave set up. When we find ourselves under considerable load, the master grinds to a halt. The slave continues to march along all happy like.

So during a recent slow-down, I took a *VERY* simple query (no joins, nicely indexed, not many results) and ran it on the slave and master, with profiling turned on.

Notice how different the results of the profiling are.

**Master**
[image: Bad performance on the master]

**Slave**
[image: Good performance on the slave]

I fear someone might tell me: "Of course your database will perform worse when it's under heavy load." And to them, I say: "You're right!"

But I am really curious if the results from the profile would suggest anything like:

- Your DB server needs more memory, *or*
- It's writing to disk too much, *or*
- Change this setting and everything will be fixed, *or*
- ...

**EDIT 1**
The following graph shows how queries slow down when we're having a problem. The gold line is average write time and the green line is average read time. As you can see writes get **really slow**. The average write peaks at around 500 ms. When things are running smoothly, average writes peaks are down around 2ms.

[image: Write times (gold) and read times (green) during slow down]

Comment: 1) What is the result of `SELECT VERSION();` 2) Is all your data InnoDB ? 3) Please run `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool%'` and post the results above. 3) Is the DB Server bare metal or VM ? 4) How much RAM on the DB Server ?  5) How many cores (or virtual cores) ?

Comment: Version: 5.1.73-log

Comment: Version: `5.1.73-log`. All data is INNODB. `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4294967296`. The DB has 48 gigs of RAM and 16 cores. DB server is bare metal.

Comment: Please run the following and post this in the question: `SELECT SUM(data_length+index_length) Total_InnoDB_Data_Indexes FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='InnoDB';`

Comment: The query came back with 541095215104

Comment: Are you for real ? Is that 503 GB ?

Comment: I am for real. I can provide a more detailed listing if you want.

Comment: Can you upgrade to MySQL 5.6 or must you remain in MySQL 5.1 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17534/discussion-between-alan-c-and-rolandomysqldba).

Answer (score 1):

## If you stay with MySQL 5.1

Since you cannot upgrade at this time, you need to [install the InnoDB Plugin](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb-plugin/1.0/en/innodb-plugin-introduction-features.html). [It was available since MySQL 5.1.38 (See the Release Notes)](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,279597,279597#msg-279597). I wrote a post about it : [MySQL - Installing InnoDB Plugin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18203/mysql-installing-innodb-plugin/18240#18240)

Surprising fact: Percona already ahd the InnoDB in Percona Server 5.0.45 long before

Once you do, you need to set the following

- Set [innodb_read_io_threads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_read_io_threads)
- Set [innodb_write_io_threads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_write_io_threads)
- Set [innodb_thread_concurrency](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_thread_concurrency) to 0

You can increase the [innodb_buffer_pool_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size), but do not exceed half the installed RAM. Set it to 20G.

## When you upgrade to MySQL 5.6

### #1: Tune Read and Write I/O

InnoDB has new options to engage multiple CPUs. I wrote about this over the past 3 years

- `Jun 01, 2012` : [I've got 16GB of ram, how should I configure MySQL Server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18670/ive-got-16gb-of-ram-how-should-i-configure-mysql-server/18675#18675)
- `May 07, 2012` : [MySQL Server Performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17511/mysql-server-performance/17540#17540)
- `Apr 26, 2012` : [Is the CPU performance relevant for a database server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17092/is-the-cpu-performance-relevant-for-a-database-server/17098#17098)
- `Mar 16, 2012` : [Using multiple cores for single MySQL queries on Debian](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15146/using-multiple-cores-for-single-mysql-queries-on-debian/15185#15185)
- `Oct 07, 2011` : [Should I use a storage engine other than MyISAM to optimise these tables or should I get better disks?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6613/should-i-use-a-storage-engine-other-than-myisam-to-optimise-these-tables-or-shou/6615#6615)
- `Sep 20, 2011` : [Multi cores and MySQL Performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5926/multi-cores-and-mysql-performance/5968#596)
- `Sep 12, 2011` : [Possible to make MySQL use more than one core?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5666/possible-to-make-mysql-use-more-then-one-core/5670#5670)
- `May 26, 2011` : [About single threaded versus multithreaded databases performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2918/about-single-threaded-versus-multithreaded-databases-performance/2948#2948)

## #2: Partition the InnoDB Buffer Pool

Since MySQL 5.5, you can partition the InnoDB Buffer Pool to reduce I/O thread contention and swapping

- `Feb 12, 2011` : [How do you tune MySQL for a heavy InnoDB workload?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194/how-do-you-tune-mysql-for-a-heavy-innodb-workload/1185#1185)

## #3: You can snapshot the InnoDB Buffer Pool to Disk

You can use the following

- [innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown) : MySQL dumps the map of the Buffer Pool on Shutdown
- [innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup) : MySQL load the Buffer Pool on Startup
- Setup a script to run `SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now= 1;` in a crontab job to dump the Buffer Pool map every 5 minutes or so. See [innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now)

There is so much more I could write, but I'll stop here.

## CAVEAT : Why is this tuning necessary ?

See my post [Why mysql 5.5 slower than 5.1 (linux,using mysqlslap)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8384/why-mysql-5-5-slower-than-5-1-linux-using-mysqlslap/8385#8385)

I have mentioned the Plugin for InnoDB Before : [Performance settings for MyISAM tables - keep everything in memory](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14775/performance-settings-for-myisam-tables-keep-everything-in-memory/14850#14850)

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Answer (score 0):

The same query can react differently under heavy load or not and this is the case here. Your query is taking time on the [`Sending data`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/general-thread-states.html) part on the master. It indicates that this query is gathering, computing and sending back data to the client. It probably stresses data on memory or on disk.

If your query is accessing data on **InnoDB** tables, you can check the output of `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G`, especially the `BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY` part. If the `Free buffers` value is 0 and you have some RAM space available, you can increase the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`. Be careful to not increase it too much. Your server will swap and crashes everything if you're going too far.

If your query is accessing data on **MyISAM** tables, it uses the filesystem cache. But there is a high chance to have concurrency issues due to table level lock when you fire a data modification. This is not recommended under heavy load.

In any case, you have to monitor the disks activity (read & write). For **reads**, if you can't upgrade memory because your dataset can't fit into it (very large dataset), you should use cache systems before hitting the database, use disks with more speed capacity or different hardware. This is easy to kick a new slave and to spread the read load on it. Be aware that the replication is async. Reads on a slave can be in a different state in a given time because of this. Monitor the replication lag between the master and its slaves.

For **writes**, be sure that it is the bottleneck because this is more complicated to scale such workload. At least, you can redirect your reads and your writes to different instances in order to stress different piece of hardware. Be sure to write only on the master.

Comment: ----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total memory allocated 4772438912; in additional pool allocated 16777216
Dictionary memory allocated 1098480
Buffer pool size   262144
Free buffers       0
Database pages     231315
Modified db pages  17355
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages read 5121894874, created 5312491, written 50416674
52.87 reads/s, 1.31 creates/s, 6.46 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000`