# Mysql Innodb: InnoDB: ERROR: the age of the last checkpoint is InnoDB: which exceeds the log group capacity

Tags: mysql, innodb

I really need some mysql expertize. I am a newbi to mysql and I am seeing some server crash of my db in the past 1 week.

I am using mysql 5.1.36 on Ubuntu. This is a dedicated mysql server with Dual core and 4GB memory and 40GB SSD.

The log errors are:

```
120413 23:57:15 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
120413 23:57:15 [Warning] option 'innodb-autoextend-increment': unsigned value 2000 adjusted to 1000
120413 23:57:15  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 2.9G
120413 23:57:15  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120413 23:57:16  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44234
120413 23:57:16 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
120413 23:57:16 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.58-1ubuntu1-log'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
120414  0:00:25 [Warning] Neither --relay-log nor --relay-log-index were used; so replication may break when this MySQL server acts as a slave and has his hostname changed!! Please use '--relay-log=e2-relay-bin' to avoid this problem.
120414  0:00:25 [Note] 'CHANGE MASTER TO executed'. Previous state master_host='', master_port='3306', master_log_file='', master_log_pos='4'. New state master_host='', master_port='3306', master_log_file='mysql-bin.000043', master_log_pos='87039427'.
120414  0:58:37 [Note] 'CHANGE MASTER TO executed'. Previous state master_host='', master_port='3306', master_log_file='mysql-bin.000043', master_log_pos='87039427'. New state master_host='', master_port='3306', master_log_file='mysql-bin.000043', master_log_pos='87846901'.
120414  2:20:34  InnoDB: ERROR: the age of the last checkpoint is 241588252,
InnoDB: which exceeds the log group capacity 241588224.
InnoDB: If you are using big BLOB or TEXT rows, you must set the   
InnoDB: combined size of log files at least 10 times bigger than the
InnoDB: largest such row.
```

My.cnf is as below.

```
default-storage-engine=innodb
default-table-type=innodb
key_buffer              = 384M
max_allowed_packet      = 64M
thread_stack            = 256K
thread_cache_size       = 16
max_heap_table_size     = 64M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
join_buffer_size        = 8M
read_buffer_size        = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size    = 8M
sort_buffer_size        = 3M
tmp_table_size          = 64M
# Innodb changes
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 16M
innodb_autoextend_increment     = 2000
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 3000M #As current Db is around 1.2G.
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_data_file_path           = ibdata1:512M;ibdata2:512M:autoextend
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 2 #For more reliablity use 1
innodb_flush_method             = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 8M
innodb_log_file_size            = 128M #Transaction Log up to 1/4 Buffer Pool
innodb_thread_concurrency       = 16
#innodb_force_recovery          = 2
#innodb_read_io_threads         = 8
#innodb_write_io_threads                = 8
innodb_lock_wait_timeout        = 50
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
max_connections        = 400
table_cache            = 1024M
thread_concurrency     = 16
```

Any suggestions what I can change.

Comment: Sorry... the first few lines got erased.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use a newer version of MySQL, if you can.  5.1.38 is ancient.  At least upgrade to a more recent 5.1 release, if not 5.5 if you can.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

At first glance, I would say that your innodb_log_file_size is way too small. It should be bigger to do two things:

- Accommodate any big BLOB or TEXT fields
- Holding bigger transactions

Here is what you should do for now to see if it helps:

STEP 01) Change the following in /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 32M
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 3G
innodb_log_file_size            = 768M
```

STEP 02) `service mysql stop`

STEP 03) `rm -f /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile*`

STEP 04) `service mysql start`

This will rebuild the following files

- /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0
- /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1

Give it a Try !!!

## UPDATE 2013-07-03 12:37 EDT

I have updated my other posts on this and missed this one

[ButtleButkus](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/6235/buttle-butkus) just commented at `2013-07-03 07:18:56 EDT`

> Wouldn't it be advisable to copy the ib_logfile* to another location for backup before deleting them?

Since there could be unfinished transactional data inside, here is what should be done

STEP 01) Change the following in /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 32M
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 3G
innodb_log_file_size            = 768M
```

STEP 02) mysql -uroot -p -e"SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown = 0;"

STEP 03) `service mysql stop`

STEP 04) `rm -f /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile*`

STEP 05) `service mysql start`

I added `SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown = 0;`. What does that do? It forces InnoDB to completely purge transactional changes from all of InnoDB moving parts, including the transactional logs (ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1). Thus, there is no need to backup the old ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1. If deleting them makes you nervous, then make Step 04

```
mv /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile* ..
```

to put the old logs in `/var/lib`. If the recreation of the logs is successful and mysqld starts up, then you can delete the old logs.

I have been using this feature for a year now. I have updated my other posts to reflect this...

- `May 20, 2013` : [Innodb one file per tablespace](https://serverfault.com/a/509309/69271)
- `May 05, 2013` : [Issue after moving the ib_logfile1 and ib_logfile0 files](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41542/issue-after-moving-the-ib-logfile1-and-ib-logfile0-files/41555#41555)
- `Jan 10, 2013` : [Finding and fixing InnoDB index corruption](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31701/finding-and-fixing-innodb-index-corruption/31716#31716)
- `Dec 17, 2012` : [MySQL Start/Stop](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29410/mysql-start-stop/30610#30610)
- `Feb 16, 2011` : [How to safely change MySQL innodb variable 'innodb_log_file_size'?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/how-to-safely-change-mysql-innodb-variable-innodb-log-file-size/1265#1265) (Last Update)
- `Feb 04, 2011` : [MySQL InnoDB - innodb_file_per_table cons?](https://serverfault.com/a/231400/69271) (Last Update)
- `Oct 29, 2010` : [Howto: Clean a mysql InnoDB storage engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4056261/491757) (Added as Step 03 on `Jun 04, 2013`)

If there are other older posts of mine where I do not mention [innodb_fast_shutdown](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_fast_shutdown), let me know so I can update it. Thanks again, [ButtleButkus](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/6235/buttle-butkus).

Comment: Increased the log file to 256M and reduced the buffer_pool_size to 2G seems to do the trick.

Comment: Did my answer help ???

Comment: Sorry forgot to update this. This has helped a lot and our server has been up without any issues since last 1 month.

Comment: Wouldn't it be advisable to copy the ib_logfile* to another location for backup before deleting them?

Comment: This advice actually set me back a lot. Eventhou the original problem was solved, the mysql daemon now requires over 9GB of RAM and commenting out the settings doesn't help.

Comment: 768MB is quite large Per Percona Baron Schwartz  https://www.percona.com/blog/2008/11/21/how-to-calculate-a-good-innodb-log-file-size/