# innodb_buffer_pool_size not changed

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5, my.cnf

I use MySQL  5.5.23-1~dotdeb.0 (Debian) and here is the relevant part of my.cnf

```
default-storage-engine = innodb
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 3G
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
innodb_thread_concurrency = 8
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_log_buffer_size = 4M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M
```

The problem is that no matter what value I choose for innodb_buffer_pool_size (I tried also 4G and 8G and 8000M). I get the following from `mysql> SHOW global  VARIABLES;`

```
| innodb_buffer_pool_size | 134217728
```

Result from the Tuning primer script:

```
INNODB STATUS
Current InnoDB index space = 621 M
Current InnoDB data space = 3.82 G
Current InnoDB buffer pool free = 0 %
Current innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128 M
Depending on how much space your innodb indexes take up it may be safe
to increase this value to up to 2 / 3 of total system memory
```

I appreciate your hints to fix this.

Comment: Did you restart mysql ?

Comment: [innodb_log_file_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size) is not a dynamic variable, so restarting is needed.

Comment: Of course. However, the parameter's value did not change after several restarts

Comment: Can you check the initialization parameters that start the mysql service? It's probably in a file in directory:  `/etc/init.d/`.

Comment: Also: Try this: `mysqld --verbose --help` and this command: `mysqld --print-defaults`. The first will have a line where it says which option files it is reading. ( I guess it is reading from more than one and the second is overriding your settings)

Comment: or even better the magic: `mysqld --verbose --help | grep -A 1 "Default options"`

Comment: @ypercube Default options are read from the following files in the given order: /etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf ---- I checked and there is no /etc/my.cnf. Other params values change as I change themi in /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, thanks [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/368233/58595) I figured out that I needed to put the config WITHIN [mysqld] block in my.cnf to take effect.

My mistake was that I just had appended the commands at the end of my.cnf file.

Then at mysql restart I encounterd

```
InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 5242880 bytes
```

To resolve this error, I needed to deleted log

> rm -f /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile[01]

and restart as Rolando told [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/1265/2953).

Comment: +1 for finding you own answer and examining my.cnf. That mistake has bitten a couple of my clients. I caught something similar for someone in ServerFault back in January 2012 : http://serverfault.com/a/347079/69271

Answer (score 2):

DISCLAIMER : Not a Debian User

Based on the comments, I would suggest the following

```
cp /etc/mysql/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf
cp /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf 
cp /etc/mysql/my.cnf /var/lib/mysql/my.cnf (or wherever datadir is)
```

If after making these my.cnf file and restarting mysql you still cannot change innodb_buffer_pool_size, then I would suspect the mysql binary mysqld. It is most likely source compiled and probably has the values for InnoDB hardcoded.

To verify if the mysqld is source compiled, check the processlist of the OS while mysqld is up and running. If you see dozens of mysqld connections, chances are the mysqld was source compied.

From there, I would suggest uninstalling mysql and downloading an RPM or tar installltion. Then, see if my.cnf responds.

Comment: copying my.cnf around did not solve the problem. Running 'ps aux | grep mysql' yeilds two processes: one for 'root' at /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe and the other for mysql  /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysql/error.log --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/debian.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306. Any other hints? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want MySQL to understand your new parameters in My.cnf file you have to restart mySQL.

Comment: Probably I should explicitly say that at the first place: After restarting mysql daemon the value does not take effect.