# how to retrieve rows of different dates using IN clause

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin, date-format

My table structure:

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| user            | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| uniq_name       | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| info_name       | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| delay_time      | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| track_time      | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

I have to retrieve data from table for past seven days, not summed one. Data for a specific date, for this right now I have to fired same query seven times using like operator:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `user`) FROM `tracks` WHERE `track_time` LIKE '2012-11-12%';
```

Which is not a good way to do. I am trying to do myself, also discussed on forums , it might be done with **IN** operator or using date1 < date2 < ....date for past seven days. For this, i am using a function in PHP in which I am supplying a date parameter, but query will take lot of time to display result on web. Please have a look on this situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are doing a range of consecutive dates, there is no need to use the `IN` operator.

If you use this to compute midnight seven days ago

```
DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY + INTERVAL 0 SECOND
```

here is what you get back:

```
mysql> SELECT DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY + INTERVAL 0 SECOND;
+--------------------------------------------------+
| DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY + INTERVAL 0 SECOND |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| 2012-11-21 00:00:00                              |
+--------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

Your query will look like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `user`) FROM `tracks`
WHERE `track_time` >= ( DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY + INTERVAL 0 SECOND );
```

You also need an index to support the `WHERE` and `COUNT`

```
ALTER TABLE tracks ADD INDEX track_time_user_ndx (track_time,user);
```

Then, the query should go faster.

If you are doing a range of consecutive dates from some earlier period, simply supply the first and last date from midnight to midnight. For example, for the range `2012-11-12` to `2012-11-19`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `user`) FROM `tracks`
WHERE `track_time` >= '2012-11-12 00:00:00'
AND   `track_time` <  '2012-11-19 00:00:00';
```

If you are doing a range of non-consecutive dates, simply structure the query using `UNION`. For example, for dates `2012-11-12`,`2012-11-19`,`2012-11-26`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `user`) FROM
(
    SELECT user,track_time FROM `tracks`
    WHERE `track_time` >= '2012-11-12 00:00:00'
    AND   `track_time` <= '2012-11-12 23:59:59'
    UNION
    SELECT user,track_time FROM `tracks`
    WHERE `track_time` >= '2012-11-19 00:00:00'
    AND   `track_time` <= '2012-11-19 23:59:59'
    UNION
    SELECT user,track_time FROM `tracks`
    WHERE `track_time` >= '2012-11-26 00:00:00'
    AND   `track_time` <= '2012-11-26 23:59:59'
) A;
```

Give it a Try !!!

## UPDATE 2012-11-27 13:52

If you want count of distinct users for just one date `2012-11-12`

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user) usercount FROM `tracks`
WHERE `track_time` >= '2012-11-12 00:00:00'
AND   `track_time` <= '2012-11-12 23:59:59';
```

If you want count of distinct users for 7 consecutive dates `2012-11-12`-`2012-11-18` (You cannot include `2012-11-19`)

```
SELECT
    DATE(track_time) track_date,
    COUNT(DISTINCT user) usercount
FROM
(
    SELECT user,track_time FROM `tracks`
    WHERE `track_time` >= '2012-11-12 00:00:00'
    AND   `track_time` <  '2012-11-19 00:00:00'
) A GROUP BY DATE(track_time);
```

## UPDATE 2012-11-27 14:41 EDT

If you want this dynamically done as of `NOW()`, try this:

```
SELECT
    DATE(track_time) track_date,
    COUNT(DISTINCT user) usercount
FROM
(
    SELECT user,track_time FROM `tracks`
    WHERE `track_time` >= ( DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY + INTERVAL 0 SECOND )
) A GROUP BY DATE(track_time);
```

Comment: I wan to display data for consecutive date ranges alone, means for date 2012-11-12: it shows distinct users, for another date it shows another one. Through above query, it shows me total distinct users between 12 to 19.

Comment: hey, second option working for me, that was an awesome query to help me for retrieving different date ranges data, can you prefer me any tutorial or resources for work on query logics

Comment: Perhaps Chapters 9 and 10 of "SQL for MySQL Developers" ( http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0131497359 )

Comment: Hey, i want this query to be run as in real time scenario, like dates have to be dynamic. Should i do for seven days using DATE(track_time) and last one is DATE_SUB(CURDATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY) ?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Hey, remove the semicolon at the end of date interval, as it shows an error at run time

Comment: Removed. Does it work ???

Comment: @Rolando: +1 from me for the long and helpful answer. (although I prefer the `track_time <  '2012-11-19 00:00:00'` over `track_time <= '2012-11-18 23:59:59'`. You don't want the query to break when millisecond accuracy is added at timestamps, do you?)

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA: yes it is, actually i can't edit from the post, so i request for this one.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA
How do you find the time to write all those very useful and very detailed answers?
kudos

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA: Hey, this query will take max 156 seconds and min 100 seconds to retrieve past seven consecutive dates data. Presently there is 35k/hr **insertions** in my database, and these **select** queries are executed alongside. Should i post another question for explaination?