# some InnoDB settings in My.cnf are messing up everything, why?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5, my.cnf

When I edit my.cnf in MySQL 5.0 in filemanager and add the following settings, I get logged out automatically from Kloxo and when I remove these line and restart server everything is ok then:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 50M
innodb_log_file_size = 15M
```

but when I add the following line and restart I have no problem and this setting has been set:

```
bulk_insert_buffer_size=25M
```

Why is this happening?

P.S.:
I should note that Horde_groupware database have innoDB tables, when everything is messed up and I `SELECT * FROM Horde_groupware.tblname` I get the error says bad information in .frm file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next time you start mysql successfully, please run these

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_log_file_size';
```

This will show you the size of the InnoDB Log Files. The names of those files are (by default)

- /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0
- /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1

In order to change the size of the InnoDB Log Files, you must

- Add `innodb_log_file_size = 15M` to my.cnf
- `service mysql stop`
- `rm -f /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile*`
- `service mysql start` (InnoDB Log Files Get Recreated)

I wrote about this before : [How to safely change MySQL innodb variable 'innodb_log_file_size'?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/how-to-safely-change-mysql-innodb-variable-innodb-log-file-size/1265#1265)

This will recreate the InnoDB Log Files.

With regard to

> I should note that Horde_groupware database have innoDB tables, when everything is messed up and I SELECT * FROM Horde_groupware.tblname I get the error says bad information in .frm file.

If `Horde_groupware.tblname` is an InnoDB table and you get this error, run this:

```
SHOW ENGINES;
```

You should see all the supported storage engines for the mysql instance. With the erro you are see on that table, there is one of three possiblilities:

1. InnoDB is not listed as one of the storage engines
2. InnoDB is marked as DISABLED
3. The table itself is corrupt