# Slow MySQL Database Import with mysqldump and USE .. SOURCE

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

I have about 12 tables in MySQL innoDB, one of them has 11 million records in it.

I used this command to back things up:

```
mysqldump -u [USERNAME] -p [DBNAME] | gzip > [/path_to_file/DBNAME].sql.gz
```

And this command to import things on the new server:

```
USE [DBNAME];
SOURCE [/path_to_file/DBNAME].sql;
```

Here is the pain I am afflicted with (the time is going up with each query!):

[image]

What can I do to speed things up? Is something wrong with my mysqldump command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your **dump** command, you could use the following

```
mysqldump --single-transaction --extended-insert -u [USERNAME] -p [DBNAME] | gzip > [/path_to_file/DBNAME].sql.gz
```

Extended inserts are better.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction
The Single Transaction option is better for dumping InnoDB tables.

In your **my.cnf** file, make the following changes temporarily

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_doublewrite

> innodb_doublewrite=0

and also

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit

> innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2

Restart MySQL and then remove these options after your import and restart MySQL again.

**Memory Tables**

If you're entire database could fit into memory, you could change the ENGINE=InnoDB to ENGINE=MEMORY in your dump sql file for every table or just the tables that are taking the longest to import, import the dump file back into your database and then change the engine back to innodb.

ALTER TABLE name_of_table ENGINE=InnoDB;

**mysqlimport command**

http://linux.die.net/man/1/mysqlimport

I have used mysqlimport to import data backed up using the tab format option in mysqldump. It has proven faster than importing via the mysql command.

**Dump the database using mysqldump**

mysqldump --tab=/some_directory/ -u [USERNAME] -p [DBNAME] [TABLENAME]

**Import the data into your database.**

mysqlimport -u [USERNAME] -p [DBNAME] /some_directory/tablename.sql

Answer (score 7):

Bulk loading InnoDB can be very daunting if your do not have InnoDB properly tuned.

Here are the settings you need to be concerned with:

- [**innodb_buffer_pool_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size)
- [**innodb_log_file_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size) (See [How to safely change MySQL innodb variable 'innodb_log_file_size'?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/how-to-safely-change-mysql-innodb-variable-innodb-log-file-size/1265#1265))
- [**innodb_read_io_threads**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_read_io_threads) (MySQL 5.5 only)
- [**innodb_write_io_threads**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_write_io_threads) (MySQL 5.5 only)
- [**innodb_io_capacity**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_io_capacity) (MySQL 5.5 only)
- [**innodb_thread_concurrency**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_thread_concurrency) (Default of 0 is best)

Up to half of the Buffer Pool can be used for bulk inserts. This pushes out cached data. During a reload of a mysqldump into InnoDB tables, the Buffer Pool becomes a open war zone between newly loaded InnoDB data and changes to secondary indexes. In light of this, increasing `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and `innodb_log_file_size` is vital and imperative.

Also, make sure these are set off. A mysqldump should have these variables being set to 0.

```
UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

You can check for that with a simple `head -20` on the mysqldump file.

There is one more import aspect: [**innodb_change_buffering**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_change_buffering)

According to the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_change_buffering), you can dictate what gets buffered during any DML operations. For full clarification on this, see [**Controlling InnoDB Change Buffering**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-performance-change_buffering.html).

I recommend the following settings:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2G
innodb_log_file_size=512M
innodb_read_io_threads=64
innodb_write_io_threads=64
innodb_io_capacity=5000
innodb_thread_concurrency=0
```