# Proper tuning for 30GB InnoDB table on server with 48GB RAM

Tags: mysql, database-design, innodb, myisam, configuration

I have a 30GB 15M rows InnoDB MySQL 5.5.15 table. It is running on a server with many other MyISAM tables (300GB db). The system has 48GB RAM. Besides the default configurations, I've changed the following values:

- InnoDB buffer pool to 10GB
- log file size 5M

Note that my `key_buffer_size` of MyISAM is 8GB and I'm also allowing Memcache to use 8GB, and have Redis installed (not sure how much he takes).

Are there any more values I should try to configure?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running ???

Comment: Rolando I'm using 5.5.15

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## MyISAM Key Cache

You said you have [**key_buffer_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_key_buffer_size) at 8GB.

Question: Do you really have 8GB of MyISAM indexes?

Please run this query

```
SELECT
    KBS/power(1024,0) KBS_BB,
    KBS/power(1024,1) KBS_KB,
    KBS/power(1024,2) KBS_MB,
    KBS/power(1024,3) KBS_GB
FROM
(
    SELECT SUM(index_length) KBS
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE engine='MyISAM' AND table_schema NOT IN
    ('information_schema','performance_schema','mysql')
) A;
```

This will reveal how big your key_buffer_size would need to be *IF ALL MYI PAGES WERE LOADED.* To get a realistic picture run these please:

```
SELECT
   FLOOR((A.variable_value * B.variable_value)/power(1024,2)+0.5) KBS_USED_IN_MB
FROM
   information_schema.global_variables A,
   information_schema.global_status B
WHERE
   A.variable_name = 'key_cache_block_size' AND
   B.variable_name = 'Key_blocks_used'
;
```

This will give you how many MB (megabytes) the key_buffer_size is in use. You should round this up to the nearest GB.

## Log File Size

`5MB` is the default size for [**innodb_log_file_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size). Percona's [*mysqlperformanceblog.com*](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/) gave two good articles on computing the right size for your particular MySQL instance:

- http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/07/03/choosing-proper-innodb_log_file_size/
- http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/11/21/how-to-calculate-a-good-innodb-log-file-size/

Basically, the blog recommends measuring how many bytes are written to the InnoDB Log Files in one hour. This is what I run to figure that out

```
SET @TimeInterval = 3600;
SELECT variable_value INTO @num1 FROM information_schema.global_status
WHERE variable_name = 'Innodb_os_log_written';
SELECT SLEEP(@TimeInterval);
SELECT variable_value INTO @num2 FROM information_schema.global_status
WHERE variable_name = 'Innodb_os_log_written';
SET @ByteWrittenToLog = @num2 - @num1;
SET @KB_WL_HR = @ByteWrittenToLog / POWER(1024,1) * 3600 / @TimeInterval;
SET @MB_WL_HR = @ByteWrittenToLog / POWER(1024,2) * 3600 / @TimeInterval;
SET @GB_WL_HR = @ByteWrittenToLog / POWER(1024,3) * 3600 / @TimeInterval;
SELECT @KB_WL_HR,@MB_WL_HR,@GB_WL_HR;
```

Whatever number comes back for `@MB_WL_HR`, take half of it and resize innodb_log_file_size to it : See my post [How to safely change MySQL innodb variable 'innodb_log_file_size'?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/how-to-safely-change-mysql-innodb-variable-innodb-log-file-size/1265#1265)

Comment: Thx! checking everything and will update. Regarding your question, I have ~25GB of MyISAM indexes.

Comment: What was the `KBS_USED_IN_MB` from the second query I posted ???

Comment: KBS_USED_IN_MB  6698MB. Should we consider even a bigger key_buffer_size if we have 30GB of MyISAM indexes?

Comment: What is the downside of having your key_buffer_size set too large?

Comment: information_schema.global_status does not exist on my system, should we update with a newer answer? or I need to do something on my end ?