# How to know the current log sequence number in 5.0.X

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5, mysql-5.0

I would like to test the optimal value for iblog files on my mysql which is 5.0.77
I found the below procedure in mysqlperformance blog:
    http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/11/21/how-to-calculate-a-good-innodb-log-file-size/

```
mysql> pager grep sequence
PAGER set to 'grep sequence'

mysql> show engine innodb status\G select sleep(60); show engine innodb status\G
Log sequence number 84 3836410803
1 row in set (0.06 sec)
1 row in set (1 min 0.00 sec)
Log sequence number 84 3838334638
1 row in set (0.05 sec)

mysql> select (3838334638 - 3836410803) / 1024 / 1024 as MB_per_min;
+------------+
| MB_per_min |
+------------+
| 1.83471203 | 
+------------+
```

But on mysql 5.0.X, I can't see the log sequence number under "show innodb stauts" output.
Shall some one please let me know a way to know current log sequence number in mysql 5.0.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually wrote about this back on August 27, 2012 : [Proper tuning for 30GB InnoDB table on server with 48GB RAM](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23189/proper-tuning-for-30gb-innodb-table-on-server-with-48gb-ram/23214#23214). Here is an excerpt from my past answer (under the section entitled `Log File Size`):

## EXCERPT

`5MB` is the default size for [**innodb_log_file_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size). Percona's mysqperformanceblog.com gave two good articles on computing the right size for your particular MySQL instance:

- http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/07/03/choosing-proper-innodb_log_file_size/
- http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/11/21/how-to-calculate-a-good-innodb-log-file-size/

Basically, the blog recommends measuring how many bytes are written to the InnoDB Log Files in one hour. This is what I run to figure that out

```
SET @TimeInterval = 3600;
SELECT variable_value INTO @num1 FROM information_schema.global_status
WHERE variable_name = 'Innodb_os_log_written';
SELECT SLEEP(@TimeInterval);
SELECT variable_value INTO @num2 FROM information_schema.global_status
WHERE variable_name = 'Innodb_os_log_written';
SET @ByteWrittenToLog = @num2 - @num1;
SET @KB_WL_HR = @ByteWrittenToLog / POWER(1024,1) * 3600 / @TimeInterval;
SET @MB_WL_HR = @ByteWrittenToLog / POWER(1024,2) * 3600 / @TimeInterval;
SET @GB_WL_HR = @ByteWrittenToLog / POWER(1024,3) * 3600 / @TimeInterval;
SELECT @KB_WL_HR,@MB_WL_HR,@GB_WL_HR;
```

## END OF EXCERPT

Where do you go from here?

Run these commands every hour for a week. When you  ascertain the highest number for  `@MB_WL_HR`, take half of it and resize innodb_log_file_size to it : See my post [How to safely change MySQL innodb variable 'innodb_log_file_size'?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/how-to-safely-change-mysql-innodb-variable-innodb-log-file-size/1265#1265)

## CONCLUSION

Since you can figure out the proper InnoDB Log File Size in this manner, there is no need to pool the `show engine innodb status\G` for anything, especially since you said it is not available in MySQL 5.0.

Keep in mind that my answer works for MySQL 5.1/5.5. So, **how do you did this for MySQL 5.0**?

It's a good thing [the status variable Innodb_os_log_written exists in MySQL 5.0](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Innodb_os_log_written).

Looking back, here is your original question:

```
mysql> pager grep sequence
PAGER set to 'grep sequence'

mysql> show engine innodb status\G select sleep(60); show engine innodb status\G
Log sequence number 84 3836410803
1 row in set (0.06 sec)
1 row in set (1 min 0.00 sec)
Log sequence number 84 3838334638
1 row in set (0.05 sec)

mysql> select (3838334638 - 3836410803) / 1024 / 1024 as MB_per_min;
+------------+
| MB_per_min |
+------------+
| 1.83471203 | 
+------------+
```

With MySQL 5.0 you have to do this:

```
mysql> show global status like 'Innodb_os_log_written'; select sleep(60); show global status like 'Innodb_os_log_written';
```

Then subtract and multiply like you did before:

```
mysql> show global status like 'Innodb_os_log_written'; select sleep(60); show global status like 'Innodb_os_log_written';
+-----------------------+--------------+
| Variable_name         | Value        |
+-----------------------+--------------+
| Innodb_os_log_written | 500034464256 |
+-----------------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

+-----------+
| sleep(60) |
+-----------+
|         0 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (1 min 0.01 sec)

+-----------------------+--------------+
| Variable_name         | Value        |
+-----------------------+--------------+
| Innodb_os_log_written | 500047017984 |
+-----------------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select (500047017984 - 500034464256) / 1024 / 1024 as MB_per_min;
+-------------+
| MB_per_min  |
+-------------+
| 11.97216797 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Hi Ronals, Thanks you for your explanation. I have seen this variable "innodb_os_log_written", this is introduced in 5.0.2, so i can see this on my machine. I got what I actually lokked for.....