# What is log sequence number ? How it is used in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, innodb, log

Can anybody give an example or scenario of log sequence number(LSN) used in MySQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [mysqlperformanceblog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/12/19/mvcc-transaction-ids-log-sequence-numbers-and-snapshots/)

> **Log Sequence Number (LSN) :** Log Sequence Numbers correspond to given
>   position in the log files and typically incremented for each log
>   record. Innodb uses number of bytes ever written to the log files
>   however it could be something different. LSNs are often extensively
>   used in recovery check pointing and buffer management operations. When
>   checkpoint (both fuzzy and not) happens you get something like “all
>   changes up to LSN=X are now flushed to the data space” this means you
>   can discard or archive logs for LSN earlier than that. When doing log
>   recovery checking LSN in the log record can tell if you this change
>   needs to be applied or it already was applied (when doing recovery you
>   do not know which dirty pages were flushed from the buffer pool).
>
> The LSN do not relate much to transactions – changes from different
>   transactions are intermixed in the log files and many LSNs can
>   correspond to changes from the same transaction.

For other references please have a look at

1 [How to know the current log sequence number in 5.0.X](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28507/how-to-know-the-current-log-sequence-number-in-5-0-x).

2 [How to check if Innodb log files are big enough](http://mysqlopt.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-check-if-innodb-log-files-are.html)

Comment: why LSN values is greater than 'Innodb_os_log_written' ?