# MAMP Pro - MySQL not starting

Tags: mysql, mysqld

I've tried other reccomendations on other threads with same issue, but no luck. Please advise how to resolve.

```
160802 09:38:03 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql
160802  9:38:04 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql/ is case insensitive
160802  9:38:04 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
160802  9:38:04 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160802  9:38:04 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160802  9:38:04 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160802  9:38:04 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160802  9:38:04 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 50331648 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 5242880 bytes!
160802  9:38:04 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
160802  9:38:04 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
160802  9:38:04 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
160802  9:38:04 [ERROR] Aborting

160802  9:38:04 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

160802 09:38:04 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
```

Answer (score 0):

> InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 50331648 
>   bytes
>   InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 5242880 bytes!

It is not that easy to change the `innodb_log_file_size`.  Remove the setting from my.cnf so you can get started again.  Then read  [How to safely change MySQL innodb variable 'innodb_log_file_size'?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/how-to-safely-change-mysql-innodb-variable-innodb-log-file-size/4103#4103)