# What MySQL configuration options require more than editing the my.cnf file and restarting the server?

Tags: mysql, configuration, performance, performance-tuning

One example of this is the `innodb_log_file_size` configuration option. [As discussed here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/how-to-safely-change-mysql-innodb-variable-innodb-log-file-size), there are a series of steps that starts an hour before shutdown and goes to after shutting down. However, this doesn't appear to be documented [in the MySQL documentation for this variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size) and I don't see a list of variables that you may not be able to adjust by simply editing the configuration file and restarting the server.

Does such a list of variables exist? What variables do I need to potentially watch when tuning MySQL to ensure compatibility with existing binary backups?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which version you are using.  By the time you get to 8.0, virtually everything can be dynamically changed.  Here are 2 types of pages, each with a list.  Note the version number in the URL; change as needed.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/dynamic-system-variables.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html -- Note the "Dynamic" column.

`innodb_log_file_size` used to be one of the worst settings to change.  You could not simply change the config and restart -- the server would complain that the size does not match.  Recently (sorry, don't know what version), the 'right thing' would be done with the files.  But it still required a restart.

In my experience, 90% of users can get away with setting `innodb_buffer_pool_size` based on RAM size, then ignore the rest of the settings.

(If you wanted to talk specifically about innodb parameters, say so.)

If you want a critique of your settings, provide RAM size, `SHOW VARIABLES;` *and* `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` after it has been up at least a day.  I have about 150 formulas to test; they typically lead to 5-10 recommended changes of the `VARIABLES`.

Comment: My understanding is that the dynamic variables are those that you can change at runtime. In my specific case, we're using 5.5, so audit_log_file is listed as not dynamic. However, I know that you can just edit the my.cnf and restart the server to change the value of audit_log_file. I didn't think to narrow down my search by limiting to values that aren't dynamic, but you can still change some non-dynamic values with a simple restart of the server. Having that final list of variables, or a way in the documentation to identify those variables, would still be helpful to me.

Comment: Links line the ones I gave you are the best _that I know of_.