# innodb_log_file_size set to a lower value than the size of ib_lofile0 and iblogfile1

Tags: mariadb

I am trying to run an application from my MariadDB installation, that needs a larger value for `innodb_log_file_size`. So I have set it to `innodb_log_file_size=256M` in `/etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf`.

Now when I check for the set size with `show variables like 'innodb_buffer%';` it tells me that the size is `134217728` which is 128M. So it doesn't seem to acknowledge my change...

Funny enough though, when I run my application (which is Rancher by the way), the `iblogfiles` are instantiated with a size of `256M`.

Can anybody tell me why this is the case? My application doesn't seem to work properly and I'm not quite sure whether this is related...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [InnoDB buffer pool](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/xtradbinnodb-buffer-pool/) is different from the InnoDB log file, i.e. the [undo log](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/undo-log/) (a.k.a. the redo log), whose size is controlled by the [innodb_log_file_size](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/xtradbinnodb-server-system-variables/#innodb_log_file_size) and [innodb_log_files_in_group](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/xtradbinnodb-server-system-variables/#innodb_log_files_in_group) variables.

The buffer pool is a cache for frequently used data and indexes, so that MariaDB doesn't have to read them from disk. On the other hand, the undo log stores old versions of data being modified by write transactions.

If you need to change the size of the buffer pool, the variable to modify is [innodb_buffer_pool_size](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/xtradbinnodb-buffer-pool/#innodb_buffer_pool_size). This is a dynamic variable starting with MariaDB 10.2, so can also be modified without restarting by executing a command like `SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size=32G;`

Answer (score 0):

Changing `innodb_log_file_size` is, until recent versions, one of the trickiest things to change.

Do you really need to change it?  Do `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` after the server has been running at least a day, then compute

```
Uptime / 60 * innodb_log_file_size / Innodb_os_log_written
```

If that is anywhere near 60 (minutes), leave the setting alone.  If you decide to change it, see  [How to safely change MySQL innodb variable 'innodb_log_file_size'?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/how-to-safely-change-mysql-innodb-variable-innodb-log-file-size/4103#4103)