# Innodb: Operating system error number 1117 in a file operation

Tags: mysql

i installed apache and mysql 5.5 on windows 7 64 bit. it worked but today mysql can not start. when i see at error log i find this

```
120616 16:35:47 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
120616 16:35:48 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120616 16:35:48 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
120616 16:35:48 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
120616 16:35:48 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 103.0M
120616 16:35:48 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120616 16:35:48 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
120616 16:35:50  InnoDB: Operating system error number 1117 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
InnoDB: File name .\ib_logfile0
InnoDB: File operation call: 'Windows aio'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

i search "InnoDB: Operating system error number 1117 in a file operation." and find [this link](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,50421) but i cant open mysql site.
what is problem?
what can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i find this [link](http://imknight.net/development/cant-start-mysql-error-1067/).
i removed the ib_logfile0 or ib_logfile1 in the data folder and it works.
but i don't know what is problem with this log files!

Comment: i met this error too, but it doesn't work after i delete 2 logfile... then i got this error: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8011/any-better-way-out-of-mysql-innodb-log-in-the-future

Answer (score 1):

from [System Error Codes (1000-1299)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681383%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
ERROR_IO_DEVICE
1117 (0x45D)
The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.
```

It seems that you had a problem with your disks