# Modify all tables in a database with a single command

Tags: mysql, alter-table, character-set

Is there a single or a one line command to modify all tables within a database. I would like to issue this command in every table within a database:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

My objective is to modify the charset from latin1 to utf8 to all tables.

**UPDATE:** RDBMS is MySQL

Answer (score 24):

No, there is no such command. But what you can do is write a quick query to generate the SQL for you like so:

```
USE INFORMATION_SCHEMA;
SELECT 
CONCAT("ALTER TABLE `", TABLE_SCHEMA,"`.`", TABLE_NAME, "` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET UTF8;") 
AS MySQLCMD FROM TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "your_schema_goes_here";
```

Then you can run the output from this to do what you need.

Sources:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,244395,244421#msg-244421

Comment: No there is not a way to do what you want in a single command.

Comment: To get this to work under MariaDB, for some reason, I had to leave the `WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "your_schema_goes_here"` out of the command.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way: export the database.
Open the exported database in a text editor and perform a Find/Replace with "UTF8" or whatever.
Re-import amended database.

Comment: Why is this the easiest way?  What if you cannot bring down your DB to modify the character set?

Comment: Because it requires no SQL knowledge. Obviously, if you cannot export the database: ease and this method would be irrelevant. But, if you have sufficient privilege to edit the database directly, it's highly likely you can export it also.

Comment: This was the best solution in my case! quick fix that came pretty handy. I was working in my local when I started having an "illegal mix of collations" error in my database for some reason. +1.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with MS SQL Server then there is an undocumented stored procedure ms_foreachtable that you can use.  Use replace the table name with a ? in the statement.

So in your example

```
EXEC ms_foreachtable 'ALTER TABLE [?] .....'
```

Comment: This article talks about having  ms_foreachtable in MYSQL [MYSQL CLONE OF SP_MSFOREACHTABLE](http://www.youdidwhatwithtsql.com/mysql-clone-of-sp_msforeachtable/624)

Comment: @MaryamArshi Thank you for this! Worked beautifully, almost a decade later!