# Difference between backup methods: Oracle and MySQL

Tags: mysql, backup

I was reading that Oracle databases have cold, warm, full and redo backups.

Questions

- How is it possible that MySQL doesn't have as many options?
- I have read that MySQL has cold backups (it puts the DB into a lock mode by itself); are there any other methods?
- How can I implement methods similar to those that Oracle has in MySQL?

Comment: Because product A (Oracle) is some years or decades older than product B (MySQL)? Some options here: [MySQL Backup Primer](http://www.pythian.com/news/1495/a-mysql-backup-primer/)

Comment: And the official page: [Backup and Recovery Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/backup-types.html)

Comment: Why is it downvoted? Apart from the obviously horrible English, I don't see how this question is invalid.

Comment: @ivanmp if you can decipher it please edit it into something comprehensible

Comment: @JackDouglas done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do backups which are not standard to MySQL

## **COLD BACKUP**

You could perform parallel mysqldumps in conjunction with `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK`

I wrote a post about that a long time ago : [How can I optimize a mysqldump of a large database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20/how-can-i-optimize-a-mysqldump-of-a-large-database/2227#2227)

Here is a sample script to use a global read lock and a monolithic mysqldump

```
MYSQL_CONN="-hhostip -uusername -ppassword"
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -A -e"FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK; SELECT SLEEP(86400)" &
SEARCHING_FOR_SLEEP=0
while [ ${SEARCHING_FOR_SLEEP} -eq 0 ]
do
    sleep 3
    SEARCHING_FOR_SLEEP=`${MYSQL} ${MYSQL_CONN} -A -e"SHOW PROCESSLIST;" | grep -c "SELECT SLEEP(86400)"`
done
sleep 1
SLEEP_ID=`mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -A -e"SHOW PROCESSLIST;" | grep "SELECT SLEEP(86400)" | awk '{print $1}'`

mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} --master-data=2 --single-transaction --flush-privileges --routines --triggers --all-databases > /root/mydata.sql

mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -A -e"KILL ${SLEEP_ID}"
```

Here is a sample script to use a global read lock and parallel mysqldumps 20 DBs at a time

```
MYSQL_CONN="-hhostip -uusername -ppassword"
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -A -e"FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK; SELECT SLEEP(86400)" &
SEARCHING_FOR_SLEEP=0
while [ ${SEARCHING_FOR_SLEEP} -eq 0 ]
do
    sleep 3
    SEARCHING_FOR_SLEEP=`${MYSQL} ${MYSQL_CONN} -A -e"SHOW PROCESSLIST;" | grep -c "SELECT SLEEP(86400)"`
done
sleep 1
SLEEP_ID=`mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -A -e"SHOW PROCESSLIST;" | grep "SELECT SLEEP(86400)" | awk '{print $1}'`

mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -AN -e"SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql')" > /tmp/ListOfDatabases.txt

COMMIT_COUNT=0 
COMMIT_LIMIT=20 
for DB in `cat /tmp/ListOfDatabases.txt` 
do
    mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} --single-transaction --hex-blob --routines --triggers ${TBL_EXCLUSION_LIST} ${DB} | gzip > ${DB}.sql.gz & 
    (( COMMIT_COUNT++ )) 
    if [ ${COMMIT_COUNT} -eq ${COMMIT_LIMIT} ] 
    then 
        COMMIT_COUNT=0 
        wait 
    fi 
done 
if [ ${COMMIT_COUNT} -gt 0 ] 
then 
    wait 
fi 

mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -A -e"KILL ${SLEEP_ID}"
```

## **LUKEWARM / CHILLY BACKUP**

A more risque method for backing up mysql is to do rsyncs. The basic concept is this:

- Step 01) About 1 hour beforehand, run `SET GLOBAL innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 0;` (OPTIONAL if your data is all InnoDB)
- Step 02) Make sure DB2 has mysql already shutdown
- Step 03) rsync /var/lib/mysql for DB1 to /var/lib/mysql on DB2
- Step 04) Repeat Step03 until two consecutive rsyncs are about the same time
- Step 05) shutdown mysql on DB1
- Step 06) rsync /var/lib/mysql for DB1 to /var/lib/mysql on DB2
- Step 07) startup mysql on DB1

From here, you can startup mysql on DB2 and perform mysqldumps on DB2 to your heart's content.

Rather than just putting the code here, I will share with you links I posted in the past on the concept of this (This concept I use periodically for making new Slaves for Giant Masters)

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/2734/877
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10915/877
- https://serverfault.com/a/257426/69271
- https://serverfault.com/a/288467/69271 (Code you need to look at is here)

Answer (score 2):

Because MySQL is not as mature.

But there are options, such as Percona's (free) hot backup for innodb:

http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtrabackup/

There is also MySQL Enterprise Backup from Oracle, but it is not free.

Comment: percona is a very good option