# Is there an easy way to copy one database to another

Tags: mysql

In MySQL?

Say I have a local database. Now I want the remote database to mimic the local database.

One way I can think of is to simply dump the database, upload and let things work.

Well, database is large.

Another I can think of is connecting straight to the database and fill the line one by one with a dedicated vb.net program.

Sometimes I just want to create a back up database in the same server.

How does the pro do so?

Comment: Check Rolando's answers. One for example: [Difference between backup methods: Oracle and MySQL](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16642/difference-between-backup-methods-oracle-and-mysql)

Comment: And this is even better I think: [How can I move a database from one server to another?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174/how-can-i-move-a-database-from-one-server-to-another/2893#2893)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need mysqldump if you're moving a whole database schema, and you're willing to stop the first database (so it's consistent when being transfered)

1. Stop the database (or lock it)
2. Go to the directory where the mysql data files are.
3. Transfer over the folder (and its contents) over to the new server's mysql data directory
4. Start back up the database
5. On the new server, issue a 'create database' command.'
6. Re-create the users & grant permissions.

Comment: does that apply only to innodb or the whole thing? Where is the directory where the mysqldata files are?

Comment: Execute this query `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir';` to get /Datadir/ path and copy entire /datadir/ as innodb tablespace files resides outside database directory where as MyISAM files resides inside database directory

Answer (score 1):

for large database you need to use command line to (clean) dump local database and after that in remote server to import (with ssh connection and also command line mysql-import or directly after connect to mysql), you need to sepcify your environment (windows, mac..)

some sources:

-http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html

-http://www.lullabot.com/blog/importexport-large-mysql-databases