# MySQL replication without baseline data import

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.6, master-slave-replication

I've been reading about MySQL replication and all the resources I've looked at say that a data import (be it a mysqldump, or a raw data dump import) is needed before replication can start. I'm trying to understand why is that. Would it be possible to start replication from a master, where binary logs were saved from the beginning, by telling the slave to replicate from log position 1 (not sure if it's supposed to be 1 or 0 also).

Thanks in advance

Comment: However, after time, the bulk of the binlogs will make that approach impractical.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Impractical why?

Comment: What is the total space taken by the binlogs now?  Now much space after collecting them for another year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the binary logs contain absolutely everything that created that master (including grants, create database, create table, INSERTs, UPDATEs, and DELETEs), then yes it is possible.

The log position you need is not 0 or 1. It is 4 (See my post [Question on having a MySQL 5.1 replicate from a MySQL 5.6 DB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82998/question-on-having-a-mysql-5-1-replicate-from-a-mysql-5-6-db/83010#83010))

Comment: 0 and 4 seem to be interchangeable for a starting position.  I have used both; I never tried "1".