# Duplicate table names after restoring a backup

Tags: mysql, backup, restore, myisam

I got this weird issue today when I restored a full .sql backup from one server to another server using dbForge Studio for MySQL (third party software).

- Both are having same properties like
  table type: MYISAM
  latin1_swedish_ci: latin1_swedish_ci
  latin1: latin1
- I am not using any temporary tables
- Is it possible to save same table names in MySQL?

Here is an illustration of the issue:

[image]

Comment: Some from Windows (where case folding is the norm) and some from *nix (where case is distinguished in table names)?

Comment: To exclude an bug in your client-software, check the information_schema: `select * from information_schema.tables where lower(table_name) = 'usersingroup'` If there are several tables with the same name, but in different case, quoting the table name might be the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is incredibly straightforward.

In Linux Systems, the file extensions for a MyISAM table `tablename` must be

- `tablename.frm`
- `tablename.MYD`
- `tablename.MYI`

The file extensions are case-sensitive

Windows does not check case-sensitivity for `.myd` and `.myi` file extensions, so a MyISAM table in a Windows MySQL instance will allow for this. Such is not the case with Linux.

In your case, let's look at the `UsersInGroups` table. You evidently have two tables with two different filenames and/or extensions:

- `UsersInGroups.frm`
- `UsersInGroups.MYD`
- `UsersInGroups.MYI`
- `usersingroups.frm`
- `usersingroups.myd`
- `usersingroups.myi`

You will have to rename the files in the OS so that there are only `.MYD` and `.MYI` extensions. You can then query each table using the case-sensitive name `UsersInGroups` and `usersingroups`.

If you simply want to replace one with the other. delete the old files, keep the new files, and make sure you only have `.MYD` and `.MYI` extensions. BTW `.frm` must always be lower case.

If you are using dbForge to make a backup of MyISAM tables from a Windows machine and you restore that backup on a Linux machine, you must always remember to change the file extensions after restoring from backup.

I talked about this 5 years ago ([How can I move a database from one server to another?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174/how-can-i-move-a-database-from-one-server-to-another/2893#2893))